# Sometimes my textbox is rendered without style

Tags: asp.net, html, css, outputcache

I have this very strange problem. I have a setup with some Textboxes, which is defined as follows:

```
<table style="width: 100%; position: relative; top: -10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"
                            Font-Size="9pt" runat="server" Width="30" Text="25" /><span style="position: relative;
                                left: -11px;">DKK</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: right; float: right;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" runat="server" Width="30" BackColor="Transparent"
                            BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="9pt" /><span style="position: relative; left: -5px;">DKK</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Now, this works nearly at all times. However, I use output caching and I've experienced several times I see my site, and the HTML is rendered wrong. Let's look at the rendered HTML.

When it is rendered wrong (happens ~95% of the times), it is simply removing the following on my textbox:

```
BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"
                                Font-Size="9pt" Width="30" Text="25"
```

This is really strange, as I can see this is applied perfectly most of the times.

**When it works, it is rendered like this**:

```
 <table style="width: 100%; position: relative; top: -10px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: left;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LeftSidebar$Filters1$multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" type="text" value="149" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LeftSidebar_Filters1_multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" style="background-color:Transparent;border-style:None;font-size:9pt;width:30px;" /><span style="position: relative;
                            left: -11px;">DKK</span>
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: right; float: right;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LeftSidebar$Filters1$multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" type="text" value="249" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LeftSidebar_Filters1_multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" style="background-color:Transparent;border-style:None;font-size:9pt;width:30px;" /><span style="position: relative; left: -5px;">DKK</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**When it doesn't work, it is rendered like this (happends quite often, however, not always). Difference is the styles on my input is GONE.**:

```
<table style="width: 100%; position: relative; top: -10px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: left;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LeftSidebar$Filters1$multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" type="text" value="13" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LeftSidebar_Filters1_multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" /><span style="position: relative;
                            left: -11px;">DKK</span>
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-align: right; float: right;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LeftSidebar$Filters1$multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" type="text" value="249" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LeftSidebar_Filters1_multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" /><span style="position: relative; left: -5px;">DKK</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

SO... ASP.NET - what the is going on? This is extremely annoying ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote it's strange and I'm sure "extremely annoying"... I don't know why it's happening but you can solve it with proper use of `css`.

Instead of writing the style on the element just give it a `class` and the style definition for that class put in your's `css` file.

Comment: While good _general_ advice... a solid & complete answer would show the actual final code.  Remember, he's programming with ASP where the rendered code looks different (see his _rendered_ inline CSS).